# Join nearest points from 3 differentfeatures in ArcGIS 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, point

I have 3 point features. This points represent middle of tree trunks with attribute of diameter. The reason I have 3 features is that I used 3 algorithms how to calculate diameter. Now I need to join these points together to be able to compare these diameters. There is different number of trunk in each feature so also the ID for same trunk is different in each feature.

So I need to join these feature to be able to know which are the same trunks in these features.

Comment: Have you looked at the Integrate tool?: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a Spatial Join.

Here is the Esri Help on the tool: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000

The tables of the three point features will be joined together based on the spatial relationship you specify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use spatial join, you'll need to set the join rules on each attribute like this (JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY; Right click on each attribute, select merge rule as join - note that join only works for strings):

[image]

---

If you want a simple way to join all three attribute tables together, you'll need to create some extra data.  You want to perform a union analysis, but that only works on polygons.

- Create buffers for each point layer (very small, like .05m so they don't overlap adjacent points
- Run a Union analysis on the 3 buffer layers.  This will output an attribute table that contains all the attributes from all the layers.